# Selector start with Specific letter and followed by any number

Tags: jquery

I need to select elements where the property `r` starts with a single letter `A` and followed by any number amount of numbers in `[0-9]`.

Example. If I have these two elements:

```
<c t="s" r="A1" s="2"></c>
<c t="s" r="A20" s="2"></c>
<c t="s" r="AA1" s="2"></c>
```

I need to select only `<c t="s" r="A1" s="2"></c>` and `<c t="s" r="A20" s="2"></c>`. I have tried `$('[r^="A"]')` but it select all.

**Note:** I can not modify the HTML

Comment: It might be more straight forward to use a regex in a filter method.

Comment: I would apply `data-` attributes to those elements rather than going by cryptic letter/number combinations. "A followed by numbers" must have some meaning; that meaning can be put more clearly in a separate attribute.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I cant. those are excel headers. Can not be modified :c

Comment: That should be something you include in your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the filter function to filter based on a regex:

```
$('[r^="A"]').filter(function( index ) {

    return /^A\d+$/.test($(this).attr('r'));
})
```

This will only return elements, where attribute `'r'` starts with `'A'` followed by some `digits`.

Comment: don't remove comments that have an answer, it leads to misunderstandings